# Meaning of "cut out"

Tags: phrase-meaning

In the Godfather movie was said the following phrase while Geary talked to Michael:

> Lut's cut out the bullshit. I don't want to spent more time here than
>   I have to.

Please, explain the meaning of the `cut out` phrasal.

Comment: Phrasal verbs can be found in dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

*Cut out the X* means *to stop X*.  It's very informal and a bit "rough" - avoid using in a polite or professional setting.  It's often used to switch a conversation from casual to serious.

> Cut it out.
>
> Let's cut out the small talk and get down to business.
>
> Cut out the aggressiveness, my friend.  We should be friendly if we expect to succeed.

Note that *cut out X* means to *remove* (with a knife or scissors), when you say/write it without the "the".

So, with the exception of "cut it out" above, if you don't say "the", the listener/reader will be confused as it would seem you were about to say *cut out* as in *remove*.  Depending on context, "cut it out" can also mean "cut out with a knife or scissors".